# Making valid json string with help of regex

Tags: json, regex

I have an invalid json string that contains variables in a specific format.

A variable start with 'VV' then key (only alphanumeric, * and _  characters) then ends with 'VV'.

There are some places where these variables are defined in invalid json string, that can in inside value of any property or inside array.

I have to bring all variables inside the double quotes, if they are not already. So that the json string becomes a valid one.

One can assume that if all such variable is resolved, the json becomes a valid one.

My sandbox is https://regex101.com/r/uE9vB2/6

I have spent so much time but i could not found a way to get this issue resolved.

PS : I am not able to resolve the array entities.
Edit : Grouping is not required, as i am using separate grouping structure. I just want to replace those variable with "was-a-var" for both in objects and array.

for input :

```
{
  "arr1": [
    "key9",
    VVvariable1VV,
    "VVvariable2VV"
    "key6",
    "key7"
  ],
  "obj1": {
    "key1": "VVvaria*ble3VV",
    "key3": VVvariable4VV,
    "key7": "value7"
  },
  "obj2": {
    "key1": {
      "key1": "value-changed",
      "key5": "VVvari_able5VV",
      "key6": "value6",
      "key7": VV*VV
    },
    "key2": [
      "VVvariableVV",
      VV*VV
    ]
  },
  "key8" : "value",
  "key3": VVvariableVV,
  "key5": "VVvariableVV"
}
```

Expected string :

```
{
  "arr1": [
    "key9",
    "was-a-var",
    "VVvariable2VV"
    "key6",
    "key7"
  ],
  "obj1": {
    "key1": "VVvaria*ble3VV",
    "key3": "was-a-var",
    "key7": "value7"
  },
  "obj2": {
    "key1": {
      "key1": "value-changed",
      "key5": "VVvari_able5VV",
      "key6": "value6",
      "key7": "was-a-var"
    },
    "key2": [
      "VVvariableVV",
      "was-a-var"
    ]
  },
  "key8" : "value",
  "key3": "was-a-var",
  "key5": "VVvariableVV"
}
```

Edit : javascript regex only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
(?<!")VV[\w*]*?VV(?!")
```

And replace with the following:

```
"was-a-var"
```

See [RegEx DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uE9vB2/5)

**Edit:** For javascript:

```
([^"])VV[\w*]*?VV(?!")
```

and replace with:

```
$1"was-a-var"
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uE9vB2/7)

Comment: @codeofnode updated the answer too check the demo :)

Comment: nice answer.. but just one more request. I don't want any grouping, removing () give error

Comment: you can remove grouping if you dont want to use it in the replacement

Comment: i am happy with was-a-var.. but no grouping

Comment: yes.. but you might have to use grouping.. is that ok?

Comment: okay, at least i get the solution. I am trying for last 3 hours. will resolve grouping issue separately